# How to make boxes on HTML page to be filled with data (text, highcharts, graphs, etc...)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I am trying to create an HTML dashboard that will contain 4 boxes on the homepage. 3 on the top, 1 large one on the bottom. These boxes will be populated with data such as text, graphs (using highcharts), spark lines, etc... However, I cannot figure out for the life of me how to do this!

I am new to HTML/CSS/Bootstrap etc, so pardon my lack of understanding. Here's a diagram of what I am trying to do... I've given a link to my image since Stackoverflow will not let me post a photo.

Thank You!!!

http://i1158.photobucket.com/albums/p618/g12mcgov/ScreenShot2013-12-30at101503AM.jpg

Comment: So, what have you tried? Do you have any code already we can help you with?

Comment: @putvande, thanks for the sardonic comment, I truly appreciate it. I am just getting into web development, my background is largely python/Django where I've never truly had to develop a site from scratch so pardon my lack of understanding. I also am unfamiliar with this site as this is the second time I've ever used it.

Comment: whoever down-voted this is a little harsh...

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SO.

On this site you need to ask specific questions with (usually) some code examples of what you  have tried.

Your question involves many parameters that we cannot guess (for example, do you need a responsive layout, what kind of elements do you want to place in those boxes, ...).

I made this quick layout that you can use to get started but you will have to learn about (at least) basics of `HTML` and `CSS` to use it and to go further.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CE5vP/5/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <p>NAVBAR</p>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="line_up"></div>
    <div class="line_up"></div>
    <div class="line_up"></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width:1050px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#navbar{
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    line-height:80px;
    background:grey;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
#wrap{
    width:100%;
}

.line_up{
    width:330px;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
.clr{
    clear:both;
}

#bottom{
    height: 200px;
    width:1030px;
    margin:10px;
    background:grey;
}
```